# Data Not Saving in Mongodb (PopUp Image)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am currently facing one issue as you see in the below code there are 4 img options but **one image comes under the popup(img2)** so all three images are saved successfully in the MongoDB except the i**mg2(which comes from the popup)**

```
 <div className="mt-10 grid grid-cols-1 gap-x-6 gap-y-8 sm:grid-cols-6">
            <div className="sm:col-span-3">
              <label
                htmlFor="img1"
                className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900 font-bold"
              >
                Image1* (Thumbnail)
              </label>
              <div className="mt-2">
                <div className="flex rounded-md shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 focus-within:ring-2 focus-within:ring-inset focus-within:ring-orange-600 ">
                  <input
                    type="file"
                    {...register("img1", {
                      required: "name is required",
                    })}
                    id="img1"
                    className="block flex-1 border-0 bg-transparent p-2 text-gray-900 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-0 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
                    accept="image/*"
                    onChange={(e) => handleImageChange(e, 1)}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="relative">
      <button
        className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
        onClick={openPopup}
      >
        Open Popup
      </button>

      {isPopupOpen && (
        
        <div className="fixed inset-0 z-50 flex items-center justify-center overflow-auto bg-gray-800 bg-opacity-75">
          <div className="bg-white rounded-lg p-8">
          <label
                htmlFor="img2"
                className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900 font-bold"
              >
                Image2*
              </label>
            <h2 className="text-xl font-semibold mb-4">Upload Image</h2>
            <input
              type="file"
              {...register('img2', {
                required: 'name is required',
              })}
              id="img2"
              className="block w-full border-gray-400 p-2 rounded"
              accept="image/*"
              onChange={(e) => handleImageChange(e, 2)}
              // value={setImages}
            />
            <button
              className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
              onClick={closePopup}
            >
              Close
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
            {/* <div className="sm:col-span-3">
              <label
                htmlFor="img2"
                className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900 font-bold"
              >
                Image2*
              </label>
              <div className="mt-2">
                <div className="flex rounded-md shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 focus-within:ring-2 focus-within:ring-inset focus-within:ring-orange-600 ">
                  <input
                    type="file"
                    {...register('img2', {
                      required: 'name is required',
                    })}
                    id="img2"
                    className="block flex-1 border-0 bg-transparent p-2 text-gray-900 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-0 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
                    accept="image/*"
                    onChange={(e) => handleImageChange(e, 2)}
                  />
                // </div>
              </div>
            </div> */}
          </div>
          <div className="mt-10 grid grid-cols-1 gap-x-6 gap-y-8 sm:grid-cols-6">
            <div className="sm:col-span-3">
              <label
                htmlFor="img3"
                className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900 font-bold"
              >
                Image3*
              </label>
              <div className="mt-2">
                <div className="flex rounded-md shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 focus-within:ring-2 focus-within:ring-inset focus-within:ring-orange-600 ">
                  <input
                    type="file"
                    {...register("img3", {
                      required: "name is required",
                    })}
                    id="img3"
                    className="block flex-1 border-0 bg-transparent p-2 text-gray-900 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-0 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
                    accept="image/*"
                    onChange={(e) => handleImageChange(e, 3)}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="sm:col-span-3">
              <label
                htmlFor="img4"
                className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900 font-bold"
              >
                Image4*
              </label>
              <div className="mt-2">
                <div className="flex rounded-md shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 focus-within:ring-2 focus-within:ring-inset focus-within:ring-orange-600 ">
                  <input
                    type="file"
                    {...register("img4", {
                      required: "name is required",
                    })}
                    id="img4"
                    className="block flex-1 border-0 bg-transparent p-2 text-gray-900 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-0 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
                    accept="image/*"
                    onChange={(e) => handleImageChange(e, 4)}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

```
const handleImageChange = (e, index) => {
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  console.log(file);
  if (file) {
    const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    console.log("imageUrl", imageUrl);
    setImages(`img${index}`, imageUrl);
  }
};

const openPopup = () => {
  setIsPopupOpen(true);
};

const closePopup = () => {
  setIsPopupOpen(false);
};


   // Add images to FormData
        for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        
          const fileInput = document.getElementById(`img${i}`);
          const file = fileInput?.files[0];
          if (file) {
            formData.append(`image`, file);
          }
        }
```

there is one add product add page in which i have to choose 4 images which going to save at MongoDB so as of now 3 images successfully saved at MongoDB but when i comes to img2 (popup) that image is not getting saved in mongo db

how can i resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your image 2 input field is not rendered in the form when `isPopupOpen` is `false`.

When you do `{isPopupOpen && <Image2PopUp/>}`, the `Image2PopUp` component is rendered only when `isPopupOpen` is `true`. You can try to inspect element and you will not see the `img2` input field when it is `false`.

What you can do instead is to set the display of popup to `none`, this is to make sure the component is still rendered but cannot be seen by user.

```
<div style={{ display: isPopupOpen ? 'block' : 'none' }}>
The rest of code
</div>
```